# Using UserProfile foreign key in class creates new profiles in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to make a basic website that uses the built in MVC user profile as the authentication method. I'm using MVC4.0 and Entity Framework.

I have a main data class that uses the UserProfile model as a foreign key. This class is a "game" class, for the purpose of relating a game to a certain user.

I've also added another member to the UserProfile class, as a necessity for this project.

Every time I try to add a new game, which has a user's profile in it as a foreign key, the server ends up making a new user profile altogether, even though I specifically made it so that it's the same user.

As a part of an attempt to fix this issue, I added the Game object to the user profile DbContext, this didn't help at all, however, and I still create new users every time I insert a new game to the database.

My models are as follow:

```
public class Game
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual UserProfile Profile { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
}

[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int Balance { get; set; }
}
```

My new UsersContext is:

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Game> GamesList { get; set; }
}
```

My method for adding a new game is:

```
        Models.UsersContext uc = new UsersContext();
        UserProfile prof = uc.UserProfiles.Where(c=>c.UserName == HttpContext.User.Identity.Name).First();
        Game g = new Game();
        g.Profile = prof;
        g.Wager = int.Parse(BetQuantity);

        uc.GamesList.Add(g);
        uc.SaveChanges();
```

I really have no idea what I'm doing wrong, any help would be enormously appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out, i have similar problems??

Comment: I just suffered the same problem. The issue ended up being that I had a "SiteDBContext" and the default "UsersContext", and I was adding the users to the UsersContext and then adding myother model to the SiteDBContext. I changed it to all use the SiteDBContext and it worked sweet.

Comment: Edit: Nevermind, I just had two instances of the same SiteDBContext and was adding to either or which created the problem. Check for multiple instances!

Comment: I couldn't figure out a proper way to solve this issue, I ended up having to do a workaround solution. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `UserProfile` class like this:

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    public UserProfile()
    {
        this.Games = new HashSet<Game>();            
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int Balance { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Game> Games { get; set; }
}
```

then insert your game like this:

```
Models.UsersContext uc = new UsersContext();

Game g = new Game();
g.UserId = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
g.Wager = int.Parse(BetQuantity);

uc.GamesList.Add(g);
uc.SaveChanges();
```

and note that you haven't declare any property for `Wager` in the `Game` model. I don't know what is it ...