# Duplicate Data Inserted in UserProfile when creating an extended profile

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, ef-code-first, simplemembership

I have managed to create an `ExtendedProfile` of `UserProfile` after `UserProfile` has been created and logged in. But every time i create an `ExtendedProfile`, Data of the User in `UserProfile` is duplicated with a different `UserId` and my created `ExtendedProfile` takes in the duplicated `UserId`. [Similar Post Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165581/using-userprofile-foreign-key-in-class-creates-new-profiles-in-mvc-4)

My entity design:

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

**ExtendedProfile**

```
public class ExtendedProfile
{        
    [Required]
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("UserProfile"), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }        

    public virtual UserContact UserContact { get; set; }

    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
}
```

**UserContact**

```
public class UserContact
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("ExtendedProfile")]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [Display(Name = "Phone:")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public virtual ExtendedProfile ExtendedProfile { get; set; }
}
```

**Create Action**

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {            
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CreateExtendedUserViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                var userId = WebSecurity.GetUserId(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
                var userProfile = _dataSource.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == userId);

                if (userProfile != null)
                {
                    var extendedProfile= new ExtendedProfile
                                        {
                                            UserProfile = userProfile,
                                            FirstName = model.FirstName,
                                            LastName = model.LastName,
                                            UserContact = new UserContact
                                                                {
                                                                   Phone = mode.Phone
                                                                }
                                        };
                    _dataSource.SaveUser(extendedProfile);
                    return RedirectToAction("About", "Home");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists, see your system administrator.");
                throw;
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

**EDIT**

**SaveUser()**

```
public void SaveUser(ExtendedUser user)
    {
        using (var context = new EFContextDb())
        {
            if (user.UserId== 0)
            {
                context.ExtendedUsers.Add(user);
            }
            else if (user.UserId> 0)
            {
                 var currentUser = context.ExtendedUsers
                    .Include(c => c.UserContact)
                    .Single(t => t.UserId== player.UserId);

                context.Entry(currentUser).CurrentValues.SetValues(user);
                currentUser.UserContact = user.UserContact;
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

I just don't understand why it would go back and insert data into membership tables. Unless, maybe i need to use different contexts for membership tables and the rest of the added tables.

Anyways, even when i use the out of the box `context.ExtendedUsers.Add(user);` and `context.SaveChanges();` in my controller, same happens. I am starting to think this has something to do with IoC (Ninject) because i made a demo app without IoC and everything worked just fine.

Comment: First, I think you should SingleOrDefault(), as you want to have one or zero results; next, what if you set the UserProfileId on ExtendedProfile instead of the object? You are certain that userProfile is correctly retrieved?

Comment: @L-Three Changed to `SingleOrDefault()`, no luck. I have `UserId` the object is there as part of the navigation property. I am certain userProfile is retrieved correctly as same data is sent back to the database for duplication.

Comment: What does the code look like for SaveUser?  Also, you need to to set UserContact.UserId and ExtendedProvile.UserId to the value of userId before you save it.

Comment: @KevinJunghans i added more information.

Comment: @KevinJunghans by logic i don't need to mention `UserId` `UserProfile = userProfile` is enough to do that for me, as for `UserContact` i am creating an new instance inside the `ExtendedUser instance`, thats anough to set UserId for my UserContact. I have this tested and it works.....troble is when UserProfile data is sent back to the database and duplicated

Comment: Are you still using the Register() ActionResult in the AccountController that comes with the MVC4 internet template?

Comment: @MattSull87 yes i am for account registration. I am having accounts register, confirmed then after they login, create an extended profile.

Comment: The Register() method calls WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(), this is probably why you're getting duplicate rows. Look at InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs in the Filters directory and see what table InitializeDatabaseConnection() points to.

Comment: Does the UserId for ExtendedUser and UserContact match the UserId in the UserProfile for the original entry or for the duplicate?

Comment: @KevinJunghans Matches for the duplicated data. Also if you can test with Membership instead of UserProfile. Make ExtendedProfile UserId a foreign key from Membership.

Comment: Since the id's match the duplicated data that indicates to me that EF is creating the duplicate to satisfy the foreign key relationship. I still think you need to explicitly set the foreign keys in ExtendedProfile. Have you tried it? I would not set the relationship to Membership instead of UserProfile. The whole reason for having UserProfile separate from Membership is that Membership is optional in case you want to use OAuth.

Comment: I have this worked out, i don't know what i was doing wrong as after dissecting everything and then put together again, all looks the same as above.